# GKE Can't have multiple ingress nginx anymore?

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

In the past I've installed them using:

```
helm repo add ingress-nginx https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx
helm repo update

helm install ingress-nginx-01 ingress-nginx/ingress-nginx
```

and could have multiple.

Now I'm getting this error when I try to install another:

```
Error: rendered manifests contain a resource that already exists. Unable to continue with
install: IngressClass "nginx" in namespace "" exists and cannot be imported into the
current release: invalid ownership metadata; annotation validation error: key
"meta.helm.sh/release-name" must equal "ingress-nginx-02": current value is
"ingress-nginx-01"; annotation validation error: key
"meta.helm.sh/release-namespace" must equal "ingress-02": current value is "ingress-01"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to set the **Class Name** while installing the new Nginx ingress controller again.

For example :

```
helm install stable/nginx-ingress --set controller.ingressClass=gce --namespace kube-system --set controller.replicaCount=2 --set rbac.create=false
helm install stable/nginx-ingress --set controller.ingressClass=nginx --namespace kube-system --set controller.replicaCount=2 --set rbac.create=false
helm install stable/nginx-ingress --set controller.ingressClass=third --namespace kube-system --set controller.replicaCount=2 --set rbac.create=false
```

based on your helm version you can pass the name of Helm as you did `ingress-nginx-01`, `ingress-nginx-02` but main thing is class name: `--set controller.ingressClass=gce`

as error says

```
install: IngressClass "nginx" in namespace "" exists**strong text**
```

**Multiple Ingress controllers**

If you're running multiple ingress controllers or running on a cloud provider that natively handles ingress such as **GKE**, you need to specify the annotation `kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"` in all ingresses that you would like the `ingress-nginx` controller to claim.

For instance,

```
metadata:
  name: foo
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "gce"
```

will target the **GCE controller**, forcing the Nginx controller to ignore it, while an annotation like

```
metadata:
  name: foo
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
```

will target the nginx controller, forcing the GCE controller to ignore it.

Example : https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/multiple-ingress/

Ref : https://vincentlauzon.com/2018/11/28/understanding-multiple-ingress-in-aks/

Comment: I tried adding --set controller.ingressClass=test but I'm still getting the same error.
```helm install ingress-nginx-2 ingress-nginx/ingress-nginx --set controller.ingressClass=test --namespace nginx-2 --create-namespace```

Comment: which k8s version you are using ? : checked the resource name based on that : https://docs.nginx.com/nginx-ingress-controller/installation/running-multiple-ingress-controllers/

Comment: Notes:

For Kubernetes < 1.18, if the class is not set in an Ingress configuration resource, the Ingress Controller will handle the resource. This is controlled via the -use-ingress-class-only argument.
For Kubernetes >= 1.18, if the class is not set in an Ingress resource, Kubernetes will set it to the class of the default Ingress Controller. To make the Ingress Controller the default one, the ingressclass.kubernetes.io/is-default-class must be set on the IngressClass resource. See Step 3 Create an IngressClass resource of the Create Common Resources section.